# How to pass const pointer to function?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

How can I have a default constant pointer in a function parameter? nil works but a regular pointer does not.

```
program Project1;

type
  TFoo = function(const A, B): Integer;

function FooA(const A, B): Integer; inline;
begin
  WriteLn('FooA');
end;

function FooB(const A, B): Integer; inline;
begin
  WriteLn('FooB');
end;

procedure Something(const Foo: TFoo = @FooA); // Constant expression expected
begin

end;

begin
  Something(FooB);
end.
```

Answer (score 5):

Default parameters are evaluated by the compiler. As such they must be constant expressions. And the address of a function is not known at compile time and so is not a constant expression. Hence the error message.

It is helpful to understand a little how the compiler implements default parameters. Suppose you have a function like this:

```
procedure foo(bar: Integer = 666);
```

Now suppose that at some other point in the program you call this function and omit the parameter, like this:

```
foo();
```

The compiler transforms that call by substituting in the default parameters:

```
foo(666);
```

and then compiles that. Because units are compiled in their entirety, it follows that default parameters must be constant expressions.

As a consequence, you cannot supply a default parameter for your function, that is simply impossible. Instead you can use method overloading to achieve the same thing.

```
procedure Something(const Foo: TFoo); overload;
begin
  // do something with Foo
end;

procedure Something(); overload; inline;
begin
  Something(FooA);
end;
```

The use of inline forces the compiler to translate

```
Something();
```

into

```
Something(FooA);
```

which is exactly what you were trying to achieve with a default parameter.

Comment: Are you asking about Delphi or C++?

Comment: About Delphi obviously. But this should work just like in C++. Suprised it doesn't.

Comment: The languages are quite different, and have a radically different compilation/linking model.

Comment: Overloading usually adds more complexion and extra code dupication.

Comment: It's entirely up to you whether or not you use overloading.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan explaines why it's impossible with the current Delphi compiler. Of course it could be possible that the compiler creates the overloaded function on its own but nobody has implemented that feature yet (and I don't expect it to come in the near future).

Comment: Inlining means that there is almost no penalty in performance.

Comment: Inlining in Delphi is horribly poor. Inline twice and possibly the compiler won't even inline it.

Comment: My experience of inlining is that it works. What tends to be poor is the performance of the optimiser which often struggles to apply optimisations post-inlining. In this case there is no optimisation to be done and so inlining will do just what you want. Anyway, we are moving well away from the original question now.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it that way. 
You can do it with overloaded methods to pass the default value:

```
procedure Something(const Foo: TFoo); overload;
begin

end;

procedure Something; overload;
begin
  Something(FooA);
end;
```